# Set a background to dynamically created list items in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, background-color

I want to add a background to the prefab when it clicked as it should look as its selected I have added the click listener which is working but I'm not able to add a background

```c#
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
  GameObject tempobj = Instantiate (amtPrefab);
  listGameObject.Add(tempobj);
  tempobj.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => 
    OnButtonClick(tempobj)
  );
}
```

I'm using this code and I want to change the color in the `OnButtonClick` method that i'm passing the clicked object to

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You want to change the whole background of your game or change the prefab's image, color ?

Comment: I want to only change the prefab background Color @EmreE

Comment: When you say background, i understand something like [this](https://previews.123rf.com/images/drawn/drawn1601/drawn160100015/50581014-Game-Background-made-from-seamless-endless-elements-Vector-assets-and-layers-for-mobile-games-Stock-Vector.jpg) can you provide some images please. That will be helpfull

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/screensteps_live/image_assets/assets/000/789/075/original/bd43df2a-c097-4fa3-a666-074da6e80a5e.png                                                  you can check  this image . imagine that the 3 items are prefabs instantiated dynamically and when i click on any item then it should change its background color from white to blue and it should look as its selected

Comment: That is clear now. Follow @joreldraw 's steps. Create a function which changes the background color, and call it OnClick method of the button. (This case is if you are using UI elements of Unity)

Comment: yes but i need the code that should be used in the OnButtonClicked method as all the code i have used is not working

Comment: Again, my case is if you are using UI elements. Unity UI Button has an Image Component. It will be something like this; `yourUIButtonGameObject.GetComponent<Image>().Color =  Color.red` . You can also define your own color.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ui Button how you are doing currently and in your Background image of your prefab add your script to change the color.
Subscribe to the click event:

```
tempobj.GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener(() => OnButtonClick(tempobj));
```

And only need to call your delegate event OnButtonClick()

```
void OnButtonClick()
{
  //change backgroung color code here
}
```

Comment: yes i'm doing this only its giving an error that there isn't an renderer attached to object and so on that's the reason im not able to change the color

Comment: well if you got this error your problem is not raising the event. check if your instantiation is right: GameObject tempobj = Instantiate (amtPrefab);